# Localize an ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-localization

I'm struggling with getting my app to localize strings properly. Feel that I've searched every corner of the web without finding something that works that I expect it to.

I use the `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` and first problem I'm trying to solve is to be able to use "short hand version" of the culture, e.g. `sv` instead of `sv-SE` and that `sv` is treated as `sv-SE` when the culture is created. This doesn't happen automatically.

Second is just getting the app to show a localized string. Here is how I configure the localization

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureLocalization(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(options =>
    {
        options.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
    });
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sv-SE"),
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")                        
            };                
        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "sv-SE", uiCulture: "sv-SE");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;                
        options.RequestCultureProviders = new[]
        {
            new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider
            {
                Options = options
            }
        };
    });
    return services;
}
```

And then in `Configure` I do `app.UseRequestLocalizationOptions();` which inject the options previously configured.

In the folder `Resources` I've created the resources files `Resource.resx` and `Resource.sv.resx`.

In my view file I've tried both injecting `IStringLocalizer` (which fails since no default implementation is registered) and `IStringLocalizer<My.Namespace.Resources.Resource>` but none of the options works. I've also tried to old fashion way `@My.Namespace.Resources.Resource.StringToLocalize`

Is it impossible to have a shared resource file? Don't want to resort to `Resource\Views\ViewA.resx` and `Resource\Controllers\AController.resx`.

Thanks

Comment: Is it impossible to have a shared resource file? I think this is correct.

Personally, I think the default localization in dotnet core is mess.   


http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1314/aspnet-core-globalization-localization

http://scottkdavis.com/posts/localizing-an-asp-web-application.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this to work. Inside my `Resource` folder I have my `Lang.resx`-files with `public` **access modifier**.

I found [this](https://github.com/feradz/ASPNetCoreLocalization) and added a class `Lang` (named to file `LangDummy` not to conflict with resource files) that belongs to the **root namespace** of the project.

Then in my view imports file `@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer<My.Namespace.Lang> StringLocalizer` and use it `@StringLocalizer["PropertyInResxFile"]`. Ideally I would like to use the generated static properties for type safety and easier refactoring and using `nameof` everywhere just feels bloated.

This works for localization via data annotation attributes as well **but** here I use `ResourceType = typeof(My.Namespace.Resources.Lang)`, i.e. the class for the resx file